# regular expression - parse classpath location

Tags: java, regex

```
$JAR_REPO/nlb/grbox/smnt.jar
```

I want to get the string between $ and first / and this will be replaced with some other string.

1. What is the regex to get JAR_REPO alone from above?
2. Can I use Regex to get the actual string like the pattern match (any method) will return the string JAR_REPO?

Please help.

Thanks.
Wells

Answer (score 2):

```
\$([^/]+)/.*
```

or, as a Java String:

```
"\\$([^/]+)/.*"
```

The JAR_REPO String will be the `group(1)`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([^/]+)/.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourstring);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String jarRepo = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Might not want 0 or more chars but maybe one or more?  \$([^/]+) also he did not say that this would always be at the beginning of the line so maybe not starting with the ^ is a good idea

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is always initial. So it must start with ^

Comment: Also I need to get this string out and pick corresponding value from map. Can you pls suggest is there any api with Regex will return this String JAR_REPO. Sorry I am not able to get your answer 'group(1)'

Comment: @rockwells `String regex = "\\$([^/]+)/.*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("$JAR_REPO/nlb/grbox/smnt.jar");
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Such type of recursive parse approach can be resolved using Interpreter Pattern logic along with parsing approach.